# How to make a modal-popup which displays a wordcloud?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I am using pure js code to show a modal popup with a word cloud using one of the pens from codepen.io . I am not getting desired result of having a popup with wordcloud, rather I am just getting a wordcloud but not the model popup. Can anyone guide me why it is not giving a modal popup.Here is he code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load',function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
</head>
 <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
    <h3><div id="word-cloud"></div></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
   #word-cloud{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body, html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
/*  ======================= SETUP ======================= */
var config = {
    trace: true,
    spiralResolution: 1, //Lower = better resolution
    spiralLimit: 360 * 5,
    lineHeight: 0.8,
    xWordPadding: 0,
    yWordPadding: 3,
    font: "sans-serif"
}

var words = ["words", "are", "cool", "and", "so", "are", "you", "inconstituent", "funhouse!", "apart", "from", "Steve", "fish"].map(function(word) {
    return {
        word: word,
        freq: Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 10
    }
})

words.sort(function(a, b) {
    return -1 * (a.freq - b.freq);
});

var cloud = document.getElementById("word-cloud");
cloud.style.position = "relative";
cloud.style.fontFamily = config.font;

var traceCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
traceCanvas.width = cloud.offsetWidth;
traceCanvas.height = cloud.offsetHeight;
var traceCanvasCtx = traceCanvas.getContext("2d");
cloud.appendChild(traceCanvas);

var startPoint = {
    x: cloud.offsetWidth / 2,
    y: cloud.offsetHeight / 2
};

var wordsDown = [];
/* ======================= END SETUP ======================= */



/* =======================  PLACEMENT FUNCTIONS =======================  */
function createWordObject(word, freq) {
    var wordContainer = document.createElement("div");
    wordContainer.style.position = "absolute";
    wordContainer.style.fontSize = freq + "px";
    wordContainer.style.lineHeight = config.lineHeight;
/*    wordContainer.style.transform = "translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%)";*/
    wordContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(word));

    return wordContainer;
}

function placeWord(word, x, y) {

    cloud.appendChild(word);
    word.style.left = x - word.offsetWidth/2 + "px";
    word.style.top = y - word.offsetHeight/2 + "px";

    wordsDown.push(word.getBoundingClientRect());
}

function trace(x, y) {
//     traceCanvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
//     traceCanvasCtx.stroke();
    traceCanvasCtx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

function spiral(i, callback) {
    angle = config.spiralResolution * i;
    x = (1 + angle) * Math.cos(angle);
    y = (1 + angle) * Math.sin(angle);
    return callback ? callback() : null;
}

function intersect(word, x, y) {
    cloud.appendChild(word);    

    word.style.left = x - word.offsetWidth/2 + "px";
    word.style.top = y - word.offsetHeight/2 + "px";

    var currentWord = word.getBoundingClientRect();

    cloud.removeChild(word);

    for(var i = 0; i < wordsDown.length; i+=1){
        var comparisonWord = wordsDown[i];

        if(!(currentWord.right + config.xWordPadding < comparisonWord.left - config.xWordPadding ||
             currentWord.left - config.xWordPadding > comparisonWord.right + config.wXordPadding ||
             currentWord.bottom + config.yWordPadding < comparisonWord.top - config.yWordPadding ||
             currentWord.top - config.yWordPadding > comparisonWord.bottom + config.yWordPadding)){

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
/* =======================  END PLACEMENT FUNCTIONS =======================  */     



/* =======================  LETS GO! =======================  */
(function placeWords() {
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 1) {

        var word = createWordObject(words[i].word, words[i].freq);

        for (var j = 0; j < config.spiralLimit; j++) {
            //If the spiral function returns true, we've placed the word down and can break from the j loop
            if (spiral(j, function() {
                    if (!intersect(word, startPoint.x + x, startPoint.y + y)) {
                        placeWord(word, startPoint.x + x, startPoint.y + y);
                        return true;
                    }
                })) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
})();    


/* =======================  Draw the placement spiral if trace lines is on ======================= */
(function traceSpiral() {

    traceCanvasCtx.beginPath();

    if (config.trace) {
        var frame = 1;

        function animate() {
            spiral(frame, function() {
                trace(startPoint.x + x, startPoint.y + y);
            });

            frame += 1;

            if (frame < config.spiralLimit) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }
        }

        animate();
    }
})();
```

Here is the codepen link I used for the same https://codepen.io/KARANVERMA5/pen/oqKJma . Please point me in right direction. Here I am showing modal popup on load from inside the markup head. Even when I am using the complete js inside the head  it does not seem to work right, even wordcloud tends to fail then.

Comment: Because it not meant to be pure javascript but use bootstrap model (with jQuery). You can see that the html is ready to [modal](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

Comment: Yes you are right there Mosh Feu , I missed to include the file for bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from Mosh Feu comment, I was not including the bootstrap script in the header which was causing the problem.

Adding this solved my problem:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```